# Let $S$ be the set of all points $z$ in the complex plane such that $ \left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^{4}=1 $

Tags: complex-numbers

*An entrance exam question*

> Let $S$ be the set of all points $z$ in the complex plane such that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^{4}=1$$
> Then, the points of $S$ are 
> (A) vertices of a rectangle 
> (B) vertices of a right-angled triangle
> (C) vertices of an equilateral triangle
> (D) collinear

I had tried using $z = x+iy$ and simplifying the 4th-order equation, but it proved fruitless.

Comment: Option (A) : 1+1/z=one of the $4$th root of unity = $\{1,i,-1,-i\}$. Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Yeah it can't be option ${A}$, since ${\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)}$ is on the rectangle, not ${z}$. But you can figure the points out by rearranging for ${z}$ - there will be $3$ points

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:** Taking of the $\space n$-th root has $\space n \space$ different solutions $\space \omega_k. \space$ The geometric interpretations of the points $\space \omega_k \space$ are the vertices of a regular $\space n$-gon whose center is at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

These four points are on the image of the unit circle under a Moebius transformation. In this case the circle transforms to a line. One of the points becomes the point at infinity. The other three are collinear.

Comment: are u talking about Möbius transformation?

Comment: @AmartyaRoy, that is precisely what he said.